# SubstringBefore move to the next symbol appearance

Tags: apex, string, substring

I want to substring string by some symbol and move to the next appearance of that symbol on some condition.

So in that code i want to skip 'Skip' subsrting and move to the next.

UPD: i need to split only if there are even count of numbers before ';'. If there are odd numbers i want to move to the next appearance  of ';'. And  i must to remove numbers from that substring.

```
  List<String> res = new List<String>();
        String str = ' "S1o2me" ; "S1i2m3ple" ; "S3kip" ; "Sk1ip" ; "Text"';
        while(str != '') {
            String subString = str.substringBefore(';');
            System.debug('subString:' +subString);           
            if (subString  == 'Skip') {
                str = str.remove(subString).removeStart(';');
                System.debug('str:' + str);
            }
        }
```

So first substring is '"Some"', next is '"Simple" ; "Skip"' and so on.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your ask. You want to remove all occurrences of a substring within a larger string? [`replaceAll` can do that for you](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_replaceAll). If you need to break your string apart into substrings, and it's formatted with semicolons as in your example, then `split` is also a good option.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please also edit your question to add exactly the outcome/result that you want from the example input.  It seems to be obvious, but in case it's not what we think, then no need for someone to answer a question that you are not asking.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you properly, you want to split string by semi-colon and store in variable split parts, if they are not in the parts list which should be skipped.
You can use `split` method from `String` apex class.

```
Set<String> partsToSkip = new Set<String> {"Skip"};
String str = ' "Some" ; "Simple" ; "Skip" ; "Skip" ; "Text"';
List<String> parts = str.split(';');

List<String> result = new List<String>;

for(String part : parts){
    String normalizedPart = part.normalizeSpace();
    if(partsToSkip.contains(normalizedPart)){
        continue;
    }
    result.add(normalizedPart);
}
```

Comment: There are some logic that i want to do which i cann't do  with split. I just didnt write it here.

Comment: @Gilivan in this case, provide more details, as it is currently not absolutely clear, what are you trying to achive.

Comment: Added into post.